# How can I make emacs' cperl-mode indent all statement continuations by only one level?

Tags: emacs, indentation, auto-indent, cperl-mode

In emacs' cperl-mode, lines that continute a statement from a previous line are indented by one level:

```
my $var
  = (1+1)
  * (2+2)
  / (3+3);
```

However, if the statement does not begin at zero indentation because it is inside a block, then if you break your statement onto a third line, you get *another* level of indentation, and so on:

```
sub break_my_indentation {
  my $var
    = (1+1)
      * (2+2)
        / (3+3);
  return "Indentation is broken.";
}
```

Is there any way to fix this so that statements are indented the same way inside blocks as they are outside? I would like the second example to look like this:

```
sub fix_my_indentation {
  my $var
    = (1+1)
    * (2+2)
    / (3+3);
  return "Indentation is fixed.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this question a boost, @Schwern. I'm still interested in finding an answer for it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen this problem in other modes too, where line continuation indentation works properly only when the line starts in column zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I confirm that the behavior you describe is present, but, from reading the sources and running under the debugger, it is not obvious that there is a *customization* which gets you the behavior you (and I) want.

Therefore I think this is a bug in `cperl-mode`.

The fix is:

```
=== modified file 'lisp/progmodes/cperl-mode.el'
--- lisp/progmodes/cperl-mode.el    2012-12-01 05:09:12 +0000
+++ lisp/progmodes/cperl-mode.el    2012-12-26 16:29:19 +0000
@@ -3120,7 +3121,9 @@ and closing parentheses and brackets."
     ((eq 'continuation (elt i 0))
      ;; [continuation statement-start char-after is-block is-brace]
      (goto-char (elt i 1))     ; statement-start
-     (+ (if (memq (elt i 2) (append "}])" nil)) ; char-after
+     (+ (if (or (memq (elt i 2) (append "}])" nil)) ; char-after
+                     (eq 'continuation ; do not repeat cperl-close-paren-offset
+                         (elt (cperl-sniff-for-indent parse-data) 0)))
         0          ; Closing parenth
           cperl-continued-statement-offset)
         (if (or (elt i 3)      ; is-block
```

Please test this patch; if you are happy with it, I will add a customization to enable it.

Comment: This seems to fix the bug. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that fixes it, thanks!  I'm going to push it upstream to [cperl-mode](https://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode).

Comment: @Schwern: I have write access to emacs bzr, so I plan to commit this myself.

Comment: @sds Great! If you want to go a bit further, could you look into merging [jrockway's perl 5.10 and Moose patches](https://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode/commits/master) to support things like say, given, when and method?

Comment: @Schwern: I would rather leave this to the cperl maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

`cperl-mode` don't have this problem by default. By default, it indents like this :

```
my $var
  = (1+1)
  * (2+2)
  / (3+3);
```

You have a customization that prevents `cperl-mode` to indent correctly. See `cperl-indent-rules-alist` variable for configuration of the indent.

Comment: Hmm. If the statement begins at indentation level zero, it works like you say. However, if the statement begins within a block or something, then it does what I say. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

As @jerome-radix suggests, the problem you're experiencing doesn't happen with `cperl-mode` by default. The problem could certainly by in `cperl-indent-rules-alist`, but there are a number of other places to look.

What version of the mode are you using? <kbd>C-h v cperl-version RET</kbd>

When debugging this kind of question you need to start with a couple of basic things to see if you can reproduce the error. First let everyone know what <kbd>M-x emacs-version</kbd> you are running. Then eliminate your own customizations from the equation by running `emacs -q` to avoid loading your init file at startup:

```
--no-init-file, -q          load neither ~/.emacs nor default.el
```

If you can still reproduce the problem with your own init file turned off, then go a step further and turn it off at the system level with `emacs -Q`:

```
--quick, -Q                 equivalent to:
                              -q --no-site-file --no-site-lisp --no-splash
```

Comment: You have to put it in blocks to see the problem.

Comment: Yes, I put copied your blocks exmaple verbatim and I don't experience the problem. In fact, when I input it by hand with the incorrect indentation and then run `indent-region` it reindents everything correctly, which is why I suggested you provide more details about your configuration since others including myself cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: I thought I tried this with emacs -Q and still had the problem, but that was several years ago, so I'll repeat the experiment again when I have the chance.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the date... I just saw the recent bounty posted by @Schwern so it seems someone else is having the problem, too.

Comment: Ok, I am on Ubuntu 12.04 with [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs) enabled. I have tried on emacs23 version `23.3+1-1ubuntu9.1` (from the main Ubuntu repo), and emacs24 version `24.2+1-1~ppa1~precise7` and emacs-snapshot version `2:20121224-1~ppa1~precise1` from the PPA, and all three exhibit this bug when run with `-Q`.

Comment: I'm using Aquamacs 2.4 which is GNU Emacs 23.3.50.1.  It comes with cperl-mode.el 6.2 and I've also tried the [jrockaway version](https://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode/blob/master/cperl-mode.el).  Here's my [.emacs](https://gist.github.com/4384294).

Comment: *facepalm* When I wrote this I checked cperl-version and accidentally thought I was in cperl-mode (instead of perl-mode which is the default with -Q). Turns out it actually [*is* a bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14043345/462302) in cperl-mode even in the latest versions.